# Prove or disprove: $A \in GL_n(K)$ if $A^{tr} \equiv E_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, equivalence-relations, matrix-calculus

> Let be $K$ a field and $m, n \in \mathbb N_0$.
>
> For a matrix $A\in K^{n \times n}$ it holds that: $A \in GL_n(K)$ if
>   $A^{tr} \equiv E_n$. Where $E_n$ is the identity matrix.

**Question**: Is that statement true?

I think that it is true because a matrix is invertible if its transpose is invertible, too.

And by definition of equivalence of matrices:

Let $P \in GL_n(K) \quad Q\in GL_m(K)$

$A \equiv B$, if

$Q^{-1}A^{tr}P = B$

Where $Q$ is an identity matrix and $P$ inverse to $A^{tr}$.

Is that correct? Would that hold a complete proof?

Comment: You start with "$m,n,p\in\Bbb N_0$", but where does $p$ occur?

Comment: Is $E_n$ the identity matrix?  If $A^{tr} = E_n$, doesn't this mean that $A = E_n^{tr} = E_n$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, $E_n $ is the identity matrix. But $A = E_n^{tr}$ is not the same as $A \equiv E_n$ or am I wrong?

Comment: What is the transpose of the matrix
$$
E_3 = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}?
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom So the statement is true because: $\begin{align} B & = Q^{-1}A^{tr}P
\\ & =\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$ ?

Comment: @jublikon That is technically correct but an absurd approach.  The statement is correct because $B = E_n$.  The identity matrix is invertible.